# ccavenue - iframe method shows blank page after click the paynow button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe, ccavenue

I am New to Payment Gateway Integration and i'm using CCAvenue iFrame method for my site. Using Query String method i sent all details like amount, merchant id, order id etc. to ccavRequestHandler.aspx.cs file.

But it shows only Blank Page without any error message. 
There are all done in my testing environment and testing environment is activated from CCAvenue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Ans...

In CCAvenue Iframe method, dont change anything in "download kit". And Use that files(dataform.htm,ccavRequestHandler.aspx, ccavResponseHandler.aspx with dll) without change anything.

Make Sure Test Environment is Activated or not from CCAvenue. if its not make call to CCAvenue they will do it. After that use test environment url(www.test.ccavenue.com/..... ) with Newly Generated Access code and Working key.

Sure U will Get the Final Result.
Hope, i will helps someone.

Comment: Is there a way in ccavenue payment gateway to click on click website without being redirected to otherwise or such a  way that all iframe redirect always happen in iFrame rather than newpage